# Firebase Realtime database fcm message sending issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase and I've been trying to make an android application that sends/receives notification. This code worked just fine for me a few weeks ago, but now it shows error though I didn't make any changes.

**Code :**

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref(`/notification/{user_id}/{notification_id}`).onWrite((change,context) =>{
    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    console.log('We have a notification to send',user_id);

    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${user_id}/tokenId`);
    const senderId = admin.database().ref(`/notification/${user_id}/${notification_id}/fromuser`);

    return Promise.all([deviceToken,senderId]).then(results =>{
        const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
        const sender = results[1];

        console.log("Device Token ID: ",tokensSnapshot.val());
        console.log("Sender ID: ",sender);

        const payload ={
            notification: {
                title: "New message",
                body: "hello",
                icon: "ic_launcher_round"
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokensSnapshot.val(),payload).then(response =>{
            response.results.forEach((result,index) =>{
                const error = result.error;
                if(error){
                    console.error('Failure sending notification to device',tokensSnapshot.val(),error);
                }
                else{
                    console.log('Notification sent to : ',tokensSnapshot.val());
                }
            });
            return null;
        });
    });
});
```

**Error :**

```
tokensSnapshot.val is not a function
    at Promise.all.then.results (/user_code/index.js:24:50)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect your code to work at all.  Take a look at what you're doing here:

```
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${user_id}/tokenId`);
const senderId = admin.database().ref(`/notification/${user_id}/${notification_id}/fromuser`);

return Promise.all([deviceToken,senderId]).then(results => { ... })
```

`deviceToken` and `senderId` are database references.  They just point to locations in the database.  However, you're passing them to `Promise.all()` as if they are promises.  They are definitely *not* promises.  This means that `results` in your callback will not contain data snapshot objects.

You need to query the values in the database and get a hold of the promises for those queries.  Note the use of `once()` to query the references:

```
const deviceToken =
    admin.database().ref(`/users/${user_id}/tokenId`).once('value');
const senderId =
    admin.database().ref(`/notification/${user_id}/${notification_id}/fromuser`).once('value');
```

`once()` returns a promise that will resolve with a snapshot of the data at the location of the reference.

After that, you have further errors in your code that you'll need to resolve.  In particular, you never call `val()` on `sender` to get a hold of the raw data that you're trying to query.  And you never use the sender value anywhere after that (so it seems pointless to even query for it).

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer. I finally understand what I was doing wrong.